# Проверка на негласный палиндром

Tags: python-3.x

**Негласный палиндром**

Возьмем произвольное слово и проделаем с ним следующую операцию: поменяем местами его первую согласную букву с последней согласной буквой, вторую согласную букву с предпоследней согласной буквой и т.д. Если после этой операции мы вновь получим исходное слово, то будем называть такое слово негласным палиндромом. Например, слова sos, rare, rotor, gong, karaoke являются негласными палиндромами.

**Входные данные**

Вводится одно слово.

**Выходные данные**

Программа должна вывести YES, если введенное слово является негласным палиндромом, и NO в противном случае.

Вот мой код.При некоторых значениях n, программа не завершается(продолжает висеть).Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить?

```
n=input()
p=''
l=n[0]
h=n[-1]

n=n.replace('a','')
n=n.replace('e','')
n=n.replace('i','')
n=n.replace('o','')
n=n.replace('u','')
n=n.replace('y','')
while n!='':
    if n[0]==n[-1]:
        p='YES'
    else:
        print('NO')
        raise SystemExit
    n=n.replace(l,'')
    n=n.replace(h,'')
print(p)
```

Comment: Если покумекать, чему равны l и h в тех строках, где они удаляются, можно понять, что они не обновляются, это могут быть вообще гласные, да и для согласных удаление всех таких символов неверно,  и сентенция `if n[0]==n[-1]:        p='YES'` порочна.

Comment: сентенция if n[0]==n[-1]: p='YES' порочна-не совсем понятно что это обозначает.

Comment: "tgft": крайние символы одинаковые, но это не палиндром

Answer (score 2):

```
result = "YES"
while len(n) > 1:
    if n[0]==n[-1]:
        n = n[1:-1]
    else:
        result = "NO"
        break
print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
n = input()
n = n.replace('a','').replace('e','').replace('i','').replace('o','').replace('u','').replace('y','')
l = len(n) // 2
n1 = n[:l]
n2 = n[-1:-l-1:-1]
r = 'YES' if n1 == n2 else 'NO'
print(r)
```

1. Читаем слово
2. Удаляем из слова все гласные
3. Делим получившееся слово пополам
4. Вторую половину слова при этом переворачиваем задом наперёд
5. Сравниваем первую половину со второй половиной
6. PROFIT